# How can I blur a div, when another div is active?

Tags: jquery, html, styling, blur

So I want to blur `#homecontent` when `#visioncontent` is active. `#visioncontent` is active when the url is

and the `#homecontent` is always in the background acting as the home page.

http://visiondigit.al/VisionDigital_Launch/index.html

How can I set a script, possibly in jQuery (from what I've researched) where it specifies when `#vision` is active, `#homecontent` will be blurred, maybe using `"-webkit-filter: blur (20px)"` or something.

Thanks, all input helps. I'm not an experienced web designer.

EDIT:   I've added a github repo for anyone to play with the code locally and see what works. I basically want anytime #vision, #projects, or #contact active or selected, I want the home or background that is under #homecontent to be blurred.

https://github.com/cweigen/VisionDigital_Launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always blur the #homecontent on click of the 'Vision' menu item by doing something like ...

```
$( "#menuVision" ).click(function() {
  $( '#homecontent' ).addClass('blurHome');
});
```

you will need to add an id to the Vision Menu item so that

```
<a href="#vision">
```

becomes

```
<a href="#vision" id="menuVision">
```

and in your css...

```
.blurHome{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

You can also have a look into jQuery's `hashChange` event.

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
    //Add class here if location.hash = vision.
});
```

**EDIT:**
Make your index.html look like [this](http://pastebin.com/VQh0F7MJ).

Things to note:

- I removed the # from `id='#menuVision`
- I changed your JS in your `<script>` tag.
- I added the `blurHome` class in css.
- You should probably move the `<script>` and `<style>` code to a js and css file, respectively.

Comment: You are missing a # on the first line of code. Also this works when the user goes to the page and clicks on the link you specify, but not if the user bookmarks the page. Wouldn't it be better to use the hashchange event? It would work both with the link and with the bookmarks, and it wouldn't require additional code changes (adding id to the link)

Comment: Was right in the middle of updating my answer to include hashChange...and have added the #...cheers!

Comment: https://github.com/cweigen/VisionDigital_Launch

I created a github repo for it, I think it might be easier for you guys to help me out by actually playing with the code.

**Keep in mind, the web particle effect as seen (http://visiondigit.al/VisionDigital_Launch/index.html) doesn't work unless you upload it online to a server or have the proper web plugins installed. At least for me.

Comment: Wow, you've really been a huge help. As I said, I'm not experienced in programming much, but I actually messed around with the script in the past where I used addClass.

But anyway, thanks a ton for the help. Any advise as making the filter smoothly transition in?

Edit: Got it, using "transition:all 1s;"

Comment: Actually, last question.

Any advise on how to smoothly transition the effect out when I click back to home on the menu?